# List all activities from a Google Plus public page in PHP

Tags: google-plus

I'm trying to `fetch all of the activities from a user's public page`, but what I actually found on Google API Documentation is the possibility to fetch only those from users`s profile page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google+ [activities.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list) API works for both profiles and pages. You can [try it with +google](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.list?userId=%252Bgoogle&collection=public&_h=1&) now.

Comment: $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities('me', 'public', $optParams); What parameter is used instead of 'me'? Is the id of the page?

Comment: Ok, found solution. To fetch all activities from my page, the id of the page should be used.

Comment: Either the id `116899029375914044550` or the vanity name `+Google` will work.